# AngularJS + Web API - How to securely download an excel file without having to log in again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-authentication

I have an application built with AngularJS and .NET Web API that uses Http Basic Authentication for security. They're on different subdomains eg: mydomain.com & api.mydomain.com

I have a secure url on the web api 'https://api.mydomain.com/downloadFile' that generates an excel file that I need to download on the client. I tried getting the file to download through angularjs using HTML5 Blob objects but kept getting 'File corrupt' error messages when the file tried to open.

The solution I came up with was to create a hidden iframe for downloading the file

```
<iframe style="display:none;" ng-src="{{downloadFileUrl}}"></iframe>
```

And setting $scope.downloadFileUrl in the controller

```
$scope.downloadFile = function () {
    $scope.downloadFileUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://api.mydomain.com/downloadFile');
};
```

This works but I'm forced to log in to the api again because the HTTP 'Authorization' header isn't being sent as part of the request from the iframe. Is there a way to pass the 'Authorization' header with the request from the iframe or any other way to securely download a file from the server without having to log in again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the iframe download method as well. It seems the most solid cross-browser supported method of downloading. So I agree with your method here.

I don't think you can pass headers, I've looked for it as well. And unless I have somehow totally missed a way of doing that (not unthinkable) I believe it just can't be done.

I have solved this by using tickets. Here's how: whenever data is show that can be downloaded I generate a ticket on the server based on the primary key of the file to be downloaded (a guid in my case). This ticket is a simple random string of a few characters and is stored somewhere (just the db in my case). It had an expiration time of 10 minutes. Which means, clicking the download url with the ticket in the querystring will log you in automatically and start your download. The ticket expires after a absolute expiration, user explicit logout or when the download was completed successfully.

Like so:
https://api.mydomain.com/downloadFile/{fileId}?ticket=fk37cltps7

Comment: Thanks Gerben I ended up going with a similar solution. In my case the file is a generated report so not related to any primary key, so instead I saved the report to a temporary file with a GUID as the file name, and deleted the file after it is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The advice in this thread (question and answer) proved invaluable, and I thought I would put up some code implementing the advice as it may speed someone up in the future

```
internal const string DownloadPurpose ="FileDownload";

[Route("GenerateDownloadToken")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GenerateDownloadToken()
{
    var userId = Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var t = await UserManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(DownloadPurpose, userId);

    return Ok(t);
}

private async Task<bool> VerifyUserTokenAsync(string token, Guid userId)
{
    var returnVar = await UserManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(userId, AccountController.DownloadPurpose, token, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    if (returnVar && !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //for using the logic to restrict access within our Dto layer
        var appUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        //hopefully changing this will not cause problems downstream - we do not want cookies going back and forward
        User = new RequestOnlyPrincipal(appUser.UserName, await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(userId));
    }
    return returnVar;
}

public static class TimeSpanTokenExtensions
{
    //a bit of a hack really
    public static async Task<bool> VerifyUserTokenAsync<TUser, TKey>(this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, TKey userId, string purpose, string token, TimeSpan tokenLifeSpan) 
        where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        var provider = (DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser, TKey>)manager.UserTokenProvider;
        TimeSpan defaultSpan = provider.TokenLifespan;
        provider.TokenLifespan = tokenLifeSpan;
        var returnVar = await manager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(userId, purpose, token);
        provider.TokenLifespan = defaultSpan;
        return returnVar;
    }
}

private List<Stream> _streamsToDispose = new List<Stream>();

[Route("ScenarioResources")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResourcesForScenario([FromUri]DowloadFileSetModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }

    if (!await VerifyUserTokenAsync(model.Token, model.UserId))
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    //logic here to test the specific user has the required access rights
    var path = //logic to obtain path here, using properties of model
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    _streamsToDispose.Add(stream); 
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StreamContent(stream)
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "easy to read.xls"//suggested filename
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
    return result;
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        _streamsToDispose.ForEach(s=>s.Dispose());
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

public class DowloadFileSetModel
{
    [Required]
    public Guid EntitySetId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

and the JS

```
function downloadFileLink(actionName, entitySetId) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST', //specify post so as not to cache etc
        url: 'api/Account/GenerateDownloadToken'
    }).then(function (response) {
        var params = {
            EntitySetId: entitySetId,
            Token: response.data,
            UserId: tokenStorageService.getUserId()
        };
        var location = window.location.origin + '/api/utilities/' + actionName 
            + '?' + $httpParamSerializerJQLike(params);
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(location);
    }, log.error);
}
```